# How to replace values in API URI path to generate full URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var api = "/self/{code}/my/{id}";

var code = "GHUYFUYI";
var id = 12346;
```

Hi i'm new to Jquery...any help is appreciated.

Using above API path data how can we generate URL like given below using JQuery?

Thanks in advance....

Result:

```
/self/GHUYFUYI/my/12346
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var api = "/self/{0}/my/{1}";
var array = new Array("GHUYFUYI",12345);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 api = api.replace("{"+i+"}",arr[i]); 
}
cosole.log(api);
```

you can do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this.  Just plain old Javascript...

```
var api = "/self/{code}/my/{id}";

var code = "GHUYFUYI";
var id = 12346;

api = api.replace("{code}", code).replace("{id}", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use regular expressions.  Here's a simple example:

```
var api = "/self/{code}/my/{id}";

var code = "GHUYFUYI";
var id = 12346;

api = api.replace(/{code}/, code).replace(/{id}/, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function Replace (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
api = api.replace("{code}", code).replace("{id}", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Enhance string prototype**

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function() {
        var str = this.toString();
        if (!arguments.length)
            return str;
        var args = typeof arguments[0],
            args = (("string" == args || "number" == args) ? arguments : arguments[0]);
        for (arg in args)
            str = str.replace(RegExp("\\{" + arg + "\\}", "gi"), args[arg]);
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var formatData = {
             code:"GHUYFUYI", 
             id:12346
         };    
var api = "/self/{code}/my/{id}".format(formatData);
```

**Credits: Gabriel Nahmias**